# String array GetLength(1) working alternative

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` to read a .txt file.
It returns a `string[]`, but a human could also call it a 2D `char` array, which is exactly what I'm trying to put it into. I'm trying to find out the second dimension of this array, as abstracted as possible.

```
string[] textFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
char[,] charGrid = new char[textFile.GetLength(0), textFile.GetLength(1)];
```

`IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

I know I could loop through the array and find the length of the second dimension myself, but I'm looking for a solution that is simple, readable and abstracted.

ps: my input txt file:

```
#111
1-1
-00
10-
```

Comment: It's not a 2d array, it's more of a 1d jagged array. If you want to make it a 2d array, you need to figure out what the maximum length of any given line in the file is to figure out what that dimension should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to find the Length of the longest line in the file (as this approach essentially gives you a jagged array). This can be done with the following bit of code:

```
int dimension = textFile.Max(line => line.Length);
```

You'll need to add `using System.Linq;` in order to use`Max`, which will return the value of the largest `Length` of all strings in the `textFile` array.
Then just plop `dimension` (or whatever you want to call it) into your char array declaration.

```
char[,] charGrid = new char[szTest.Length, dimension];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. You should also add that you need to be `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes each row has the same number of char.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String path = @"input.txt";
            string[] textFile = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            char[,] charGrid = new char[textFile.Length, textFile[0].Length];
            int i, j;
            i = 0;
            foreach (string line in textFile)
            {
                j = 0;
                foreach (char c in line)
                {
                    charGrid[i, j] = c;
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(charGrid[0,0] +  "" + charGrid[0, 1] + "" + charGrid[0, 2]);
            Console.WriteLine(charGrid[1, 0] + "" + charGrid[1, 1] + "" + charGrid[1, 2]);
            Console.WriteLine(charGrid[2, 0] + "" + charGrid[2, 1] +  "" + charGrid[2, 2]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```